# Google Dart: change event for IListElement

Tags: dom, dart

I'm wondering if you can listen for when the elements of a `UListElement` has changed (i.e. `LIElement` added or removed)?

```dart
UListElement toDoList = query('#to-do-list');
LIElement newToDo = new LIElement();
newToDo.text = "New Task";
toDoList.elements.add(newToDo);
// how do I execute some code once the newToDo has been added to the toDoList?
```

I'm assuming `elements.add()` is asynchronous as I come from an ActionScript background. Is this a valid assumption?

Answer (score 3):

Higher level frameworks give you events for this, but at the HTML5 API level, you have to use a MutationObserver.

Here's an example where a mutation observer can be set on any DOM Element object.  The handler can then process the mutation events as needed.

```
void setMutationObserver(Element element){
  new MutationObserver(mutationHandler)
    .observe(element, subtree: true, childList: true, attributes: false);
}

void mutationHandler(List<MutationRecord> mutations,
                    MutationObserver observer){
  for (final MutationRecord r in mutations){
    r.addedNodes.forEach((node){
      // do stuff here
    });

    r.removedNodes.forEach((node){
      // or here
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`element.elements.add(otherElement)` is synchronous and is the equivalent of `element.appendChild(otherElement)` in Javascript (ie. [DOM Level 2 Core : appendChild](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-184E7107)).

Answer (score 0):

You may also be interested in our work with MDV:

- http://blog.sethladd.com/2012/11/your-first-input-field-binding-with-web.html
- http://blog.sethladd.com/2012/11/your-first-model-driven-view-with-dart.html